# Bind ViewModel with List<T> to a specific control

Tags: c#, list, html-helper, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a ViewModel which contains a List.

The examples I've seen show:

1. Accessing the List items by iterating over all of them:

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < Model.Compliances.Count; i++)  
   {
       <%=Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Compliances[i].ComplianceId) %>  
       <%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Compliances[i].ComplianceName) %>       
   }
   ```
2. OR Specifying a hard coded position in the List:

   ```
   <%=Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Compliances[2].ComplianceId) %>
   <%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Compliances[2].ComplianceName) %>
   ```

I am wondering if there is some way to bind a particular List item to a control by something more concrete like its id, instead of what position it happens to have in the List?

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: Control? Id?  What are you referring to?  MVC doesn't have these concepts.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch The HTML helper methods can render controls like a text box as shown in my example above. Its value can then be bound to something in the view model.  In my case it is a List<Compliance> which I only seem to be able to access by using its index position in the List.  
The Id I am referring to is a unique id property on each List item instead of using their index position.

Comment: You have to get out of the habit of thinking of client-side controls as being "bound" to anything server side.  This is WebForms thinking.  HtmlHelpers are merely tools to create HTML form elements that are formatted in a way that the default model binder can understand when posted.  This is not "binding".  The binding is what happens on the server, via the ModelBinder.  This takes name/value pairs posted to the server and tries to match them up with objects in your model.  Those might be from controls, or they might be from other sources.. (javascript, for instance).

Comment: Can you use LINQ? `x.Compliances.Where(c => c.id == element.id).FirstOrDefault()` or however you access the element's id in this case.

Comment: @Eris Unfortunately no, it throws an InvalidOperation exception stating: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are stuck in WebForms terminology.

These are called Html Helpers, not controls.  These helpers render HTML and do not "bind" anything in the sense you are thinking of.  They're called helpers because they simply help to format the data in the correct way.

The reason that the helpers use specific indexes as you see is because the when the forms are posted back to the server, they must be indexed on a 0 based form so the model binder can discover them and recreate the model.  It does this by two things, name and index, not by id's of values or anything else.

So if you want a list to be bound on postback, then it must be a 0 based index... OR it must use an "Index" value, as defined in the "non-sequential indexes" section of this article:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/